# python split lines of file maybe every 2 lines and create dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, split, lines

I have a file like:

```
AFA MT 0 0  1.22 259 169 FOD 0 50.01 1.3  1.370  0.00  -0.02  1.78 0  0.0
                        S 2 50.620 1.960 2.452 0.00 -0.49 0.31
MKE MS 0 0  4.22 256 149 MDO 1 30.00 1.4  2.370  3.00  -0.52  4.82 0 0.0
KTE KL 0 0  1.22 259 169 FID 0 10.01 2.0  2.470  1.00  -0.12  0.78 1  1.0
                        S 3 70.610 1.960 2.52 0.00 -0.19 0.41
... 
...
```

S lines are not always there, but always start with S .

And  I like to split it and create a dictionary with keys only the first fields (AFA, KTE ...) but also keep the "S 2 50.60 ... 0.31" part as the keys values of the previous key, whenecver they exist. 
(aka merge the S lines with the previous line whenever they ocure).

So far I did:

```
import collections
st = {} 
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if len(line.split())==17 or len(line.split())==8 :
            key, value = line.split(None, 1)
            st[key] = (value.split())
            #order output as the order in file
            st=collections.OrderedDict(st)
            print ([key] ,[value])
```

but this gives me:

```
['AFA'] ['MT 0 0  1.22 259 169 FOD 0 50.01 1.3  1.370  0.00  -0.02  1.78 0  0.0']
                    ['S'] ['2 50.620 1.960 2.452 0.00 -0.49 0.31']
['MKE'] ['MS 0 0  4.22 256 149 MDO 1 30.00 1.4  2.370  3.00  -0.52  4.82 0 0.0']
['KTE'] ['KL 0 0  1.22 259 169 FID 0 10.01 2.0  2.470  1.00  -0.12  0.78 1  1.0']
                    ['S'] ['3 70.610 1.960 2.52 0.00 -0.19 0.41']
```

while I try and want though to get:

```
['AFA'] ['MT 0 0  1.22 259 169 FOD 0 50.01 1.3  1.370  0.00  -0.02  1.78 0  0.0 S 2 50.620 1.960 2.452 0.00 -0.49 0.31']
['MKE'] ['MS 0 0  4.22 256 149 MDO 1 30.00 1.4  2.370  3.00  -0.52  4.82 0 0.0']
['KTE'] ['KL 0 0  1.22 259 169 FID 0 10.01 2.0  2.470  1.00  -0.12  0.78 1  1.0 S 3 70.610 1.960 2.52 0.00 -0.19 0.41']
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic you could use is:

- remember the last non-S line you've read
- If you read an S-line, add it to the remembered non-S line & put that in your dictionary that, then forget the remembered non-S line
- If you read a non-S-line, put any remembered non-S line in your dictionary & remember the new line instead
- When you are done with the file, put any remembered non-S line in your dictionary

This seems to do what you want, without much modification to your attempt:

```
import pprint
st = {} 
with open("file.txt") as f: 
    for line in f: 
        if len(line.split())==17 : 
            key, value = line.split(None, 1) 
            st[key] = (value.split()) 
        elif len(line.split())==8 : 
            st[key] += line.split()
pprint.pprint(st)
```

Comment: thnx for the reply and yr time, but the thing is I try and can not do that

Comment: If you show how you tried, someone can help you fix it.

Comment: `import collections

   st = {}

   with open("file.txt") as f:

        head_lines = 4

        for line in f:

           if len(line.split())==17 :

                key, value = line.split(None, 1)

                st[key] = (value.split())

            elif len(line.split())==8 :

                st[key] = line;

                #order output as the order in file
               st=collections.OrderedDict(st)
               print ([key] ,[value])`

Comment: thnx a lot! and enjoy the weekend